# What is the common name for control container that can be panned around by dragging with the mouse?

Tags: html, vue.js, user-interface, controls

I want to create a container that will be much wider than the width of the page. The user will be able to pan by dragging empty space between controls. (No zooming involved).

What is such a container control called?

I'd like to find an existing thing in Vue, but without knowing what to call it, it's hard to find.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a library called panzoom, which allows you to create a zoomable and panable area around other components. You can install it with
npm install @panzoom/panzoom

Another option is to use SvgPanZoom, which is a library that works with SVG elements. You can also install it with
npm install svg-pan-zoom